# Serveral models in one view ASP.net core with EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a Dashboard of two tables and a chart of data in the database using ASP.net Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.

This the  teacher model class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }

    public Sring Name { get; set; }

    public  int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

this is the course model class :

```
 public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }

    public Sring Name { get; set; }

    public Sring TargetClass { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel class is as follows:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{

    public List<Course> Course { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

the index page is :

```
    <h2> Table of Teacher</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Teacher item in Model.Teacher)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Age
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>

<h2> Table of Courses</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> TargetClass</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Teacher item in Model.Course)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.TargetClass
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

The home controller is :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   public  async Task<IActionResult> Index() 
    {
        var qry =  await _context.Teacher.ToListAsync();

        var Teachers = new List<Teacher>(){};

        var Courses = new List<Courses>() { };

        var Dash = new DashboardViewModel {

        Course = Courses,
        Teacher = Teachers
        };

        return View(Dash);
    }
```

The Problem appears when trying to pass the data from qry variable to list.
Question : How I can pass the data from EF to List of Teachers as the example?

```
        var qry =  _context.Teacher.ToListAsync();

        var Teachers = new List<Teacher>(){qry};
```

Without convert error :
cannot convert from `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<School.Models.Teacher>>' to 'School.Models.Teacher'`

Comment: You need to `await` asynchronous calls such as `ToListAsync()`. When you do, it will become a `List<Teacher>` because if you don't then it returns a task. You can try changing the line to `var Teachers =  await _context.Teacher.ToListAsync();`. This also means your Index action should be changed to `public async Task<IActionResult> Index()`. If you don't like the hassle, simply use `ToList()` instead of `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: @jegtugado thanks for your suggestions, I tried both solutions but the  error still

Comment: Can you update your controller code based on the changes that jegtugado suggested that you said is still throwing an error?

Comment: @BryanLewis I updated the controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't do this in comments, so I will put this here and then I can amend the answer if it's not quite right.  You don't need to create empty lists beforehand, just create the ViewModel all in one shot.  As I think jegtugado was trying to suggest, the Index() code should look something like:

```
   public  async Task<IActionResult> Index() 
    {
        var Dash = new DashboardViewModel {
            Course = await _context.Course.ToListAsync(),
            Teacher = await _context.Teacher.ToListAsync()
        };

        return View(Dash);
    }
```

This is assuming your DbSets are called Teacher and Course (but these are often plural, so double check that).